# ImportError when running pytest in gitlab CI

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci, pytest-mock

I have created a Python package with the following structure

```
root-dir
├── bar-pack
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── functions.py
│   └── test
│       └── __init__.py
│       └── test_functions.py
├── setup.py
```

When I run the following locally, it works fine :

```
$ pytest bar-pack/test -v
```

So I added the command to my .giltab-ci.yml, so the testing stage looks like this :

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.10
  rules :
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: manual
  before_script:
    - pip install pytest pytest-mock
  script:
    - pytest bar-pack/test -v
```

When the CI runs I, get this error :

```
ImportError while importing test module '/builds/mygitlab-projects/root-dir/bar-pack/test/test_functions.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
bar-pack/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    __version__ = version("bar-pack")
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py:996: in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py:969: in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py:548: in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
E   importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for bar-pack
```

By the way :

```
# The bar-pack/__init__.py file looks like this :

from importlib.metadata import version
__version__ = version("bar-pack")
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html):

> importlib_metadata operates on third-party distribution packages installed into Python’s site-packages directory via tools such as pip. Specifically, it works with distributions with discoverable dist-info or egg-info directories, and metadata defined by the Core metadata specifications.

In your gitlab job, there is no dist-info or egg-info directories present or other way for this to be detected.

So, you can resolve this by installing the package using `pip` first in order to get its version using `importlib.metadata.version()`.

```yaml
  before_script:
    - pip install pytest pytest-mock
    - pip install .
```

Locally, you've probably already generated dist/egg-info by either doing an editable install or building.